# Entity framework generates columns which are not needed based on inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble getting the right database structure from my models. My models have some inheritance which is where Entity Framework can't figure it out on its own (I think).

The classes. I have multiple of these setups which are very similar. Only showing one:

```cs
public class Answer {
    // ...
}


public class PartialAnswer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class PartialSortedAnswer : PartialAnswer {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class PartialRepeatingSortedAnswer : PartialSortedAnswer {
    public int Set { get; set; }
    // ...
}


public class MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted : Answer {
    public virtual IEnumerable<Partials.PartialRepeatingSortedAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I have set up the inherited entities with this code in my context:

```cs
    builder.Entity<PartialSortedAnswer>();
    builder.Entity<PartialRepeatingSortedAnswer>();
    builder.Entity<MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted>();
    // ...
```

When creating a migration Entity Framework creates a new table `PartialAnswers`. This table has the following columns:

- Id
- AnswerId
- Discriminator
- Key
- Set
- MultipleAnswersRepeatingSortedId
- ...

I understand all columns, these are all based on the different types I have. The only thing which I can't seem to figure out is this final `MultipleAnswersRepeatingSortedId` column. Entity Framework creates a foreign key relation to the `Answers` table for this column. Why isn't EF using the already defined `AnswerId`?

I've tried to specify the column name but this doesn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

`MultipleAnswersRepeatingSortedId` is the FK for the one-to-many relationship from the property `MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted.Answers`.

So `MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted` 1.....* `PartialAnswer`.
Which means we could have a property `PartialAnswer.MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted`
Giving us the FK `PartialAnswer.MultipleAnswersRepeatingSortedId`

---

`PartialAnswer.AnswerId` basically means `PartialAnswer` *.....1 `Answer`.
Which means you could have a property `Answer.PartialAnswers`, that is different from the `MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted.Answers`.

---

My suggestion is to remove the `MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted.Answers` property and just define `Answer.PartialAnswers`.

Comment: Okay I understand. But can I have this new FK use the same column as `AnswerId`. Since `MultipleAnswersRepeatingSorted` is an `Answer` the `AnswerId` column and the new column should always have the same value.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I found out that I can use InverseProperty to have it use the same column. Sadly I can only do this on 2 out of the 4 types of `Answer`. Doesn't matter which one I choose, there's just a maximum of 2. Seems to be a bug in EF Core since I get this error: `The convention invocations have reached the recursion limit. This is likely an issue in EF Core, please report it.`

Thanks for thinking with me. I'll just leave it at 2 InverseProperties for now and maybe try later to have them all use the same column.